# Swift - Force derived classes to implement static method

Tags: swift, static, abstract

I want to force all classes derived from my base class to have to implement a static variable, without forcing every derived class to implement a protocol.

Here's a sample:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case BaseType
    case DerivedType
}

protocol Typed {
    static var classType: SomeEnum { get }
}

class BaseClass : Typed {
    static var classType: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.BaseType
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    // ERROR: Cannot override with a stored property 'classType'
    static var classType: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.DerivedType
}
```

The code below here works but requires the implementor of every class derived from `BaseClass` to remember to also derived from the protocol `Typed`, and it also means that `BaseClass` itself cannot define `classType`:

```
class BaseClass {
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass, Typed {
    static var classType: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.DerivedType
}
```

This example below doesn't work either, I get a different error:

```
class BaseClass {
    static var classType: SomeEnum {
        get { return SomeEnum.BaseType }
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    // ERROR: Class var overrides 'final' class var
    static var classType: SomeEnum {
        get { return SomeEnum.DerivedType }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable can't be redefined by the subclass (it is already there). It should be set during initialization instead.

```
protocol Typed {
    var classType: SomeEnum { get }
}

class BaseClass : Typed {
    var classType: SomeEnum = SomeEnum.BaseType
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        classType = SomeEnum.DerivedType
    }
}
```

As far as I know,  in Swift (or Objective-C) it is not possible for a class to force its subclass to redefine a method or set a property.

Comment: It doesn't sound like there's a good compile-time solution in Swift, which is frustrating, but since there isn't a solution your answer seems to be correct, so I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It is an inheritance question. In inheritance a sub class can not declare the variable name Equals base class variable name. This is because the sub class will get all public methods and variables from the base class, so you can not do this. Get a new variable for the sub class.

It looks like this:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    static var newclassType : SomeEnum = SomeEnum.DerivedType
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Comment: The issue with this approach is there is nothing requiring the derived classes to implement the static var. I need all of the derived types to have this static information. Other languages allow this, but I'm new to Swift so I was hoping it was available in Swift and that maybe I just don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: I have try in others languages , I use C++, C++ doesn't have Protocol . It is new to make a virtual function to replace protocol. The  situation is like your saying that.  I think that apple can not changes this property in Swift, it is because swift is strong type languages.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing

Comment: In C++ the base class can have a pure virtual method (abstract), forcing all derived classes to implement a method (a compile-time enforcement). In Swift it seems like you can only enforce that by calling fatalError() if it's not implemented, something only enforceable at runtime. In C# you can have an abstract class to force this requirement, or an Interface.

Comment: You've provided a link to data about an abstract class. I would love to have an abstract class like C++/C# provide, that's what I'm looking to reproduce. With an abstract class I can implement methods and have variables, but require that derived classes implement specific methods as well. I can't see a way to do that with Swift.